# Splitting range of values in one cell to multiple observations using R

Tags: r, range, data-cleaning

Working on a slightly messy data where in one cell includes range of values and it is as showcased below :-

```
Code           Flag
69660-69663      1
69666-69667      2
```

The desired output is :-

```
Code   Flag
69660    1
69660    1
69660    1
69660    1
69666    2
69667    2
```

Is there a package which will handle range of values and split it into different observations?

I tried this solution :-

```
mydb2<-cSplit(mydb, "Code", sep = "-", direction = "long")
```

This just splits the value into two different observations instead of range of observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possibility -

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    s <- strsplit(as.character(x), "-")[[1]]
    data.frame(Code = s[1]:s[2], Flag = y)
}

do.call(rbind, Map(f, df$Code, df$Flag))
#    Code Flag
# 1 69660    1
# 2 69661    1
# 3 69662    1
# 4 69663    1
# 5 69666    2
# 6 69667    2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try making use of `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydf, "Code", "-")[, list(Code = Code_1:Code_2), by = Flag]
##    Flag Code
## 1:    1    1
## 2:    1    2
## 3:    1    3
## 4:    2    5
## 5:    2    6
## 6:    2    7
## 7:    2    8
```

Comment: There was a warning message and it was not giving the desired output. Hence, edited the question which replicates actual data-set. The logic still remains the same.

Comment: My code still works with your new sample. Can you provide a sample that generates the warning message you say you are getting?

Comment: What version of "splitstackshape" do you have?

Comment: splitstackshape version is 1.4.2

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In Code_1:Code_2 :
  numerical expression has 635 elements: only the first used
2: In Code_1:Code_2 :
  numerical expression has 635 elements: only the first used
3: In Code_1:Code_2 :
  numerical expression has 2447 elements: only the first used
4: In Code_1:Code_2 :
  numerical expression has 2447 elements: only the first used

Comment: @x1carbon, can you share the output of the first few lines of your actual data using `dput`. (Say `dupt(head(mydb, 3))` or something. Or isolate which rows seem to be creating the problem.